# Bicep for acsemail API Connection

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-communication-services

Has anyone managed to create the Bicep for an acs API connection?  When it is created through the Logic App designer, you specify a connection string.  However, I cannot work out the correct syntax for the Bicep file.
If I specify this:

```
resource cn_communicationservices 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: connectionType
  location: location
  kind: 'V2'
  properties: {
    displayName: connectionName
    parameterValues: {
      connectionString: connString
    }
    api: {
      name:         connectionType
      displayName:  connectionName
      description:  'Connector to send Email using the domains linked to the Azure Communication Services in your subscription'
      iconUri:      'https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1619/1.0.1619.3185/${connectionType}/icon.png'
      id:           '/subscriptions/${subId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/acsemail'
      type:         'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    testLinks: []
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Parameter  'connectionString' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a
> connection parameter when the API was registered
> I have tried many other things but none have worked, has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below parameter to feed the ACS connection string,

```
     parameterValues: {
      api_key       : connString
    }
```

I ran a local test and confirmed it works to create a API connection.

Comment: Hi, you beat me to it!  I received a response and great help from Divyansh Rohmetra at Microsoft.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I also received the same error when I tried in my environment previously. After a workaround on this, I found a way to avoid it as follows.*

*Error:*

> Parameter 'connectionString' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter.

***To resolve:***

In this case, you can use `customParameterValues{}`block to provide the parameters you need to add.

I've tried the sample script for creating a web connection as shown and you can modify it as per your requirement.

```bash
param acsName string
param acsKeyVaultName string
param acsSecretName string
param storageAccount string
param storageAccountRG string
param storageAccountContainer string
param location string = 'centralus'

resource acsConn 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: acsName
  location: location
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: ''
    }
    displayName: acsName
    parameterValues: {
      clientId: ''
      clientSecret: '[parameters(\'acsSecret\')]'
      tenantId: 'xxxxxx'
    }
    customParameterValues: {
      storageAccount: <storageAccount>
      storageAccountRG: ''
      storageAccountContainer: ''
    }
  }
}

output acsConnId string = acsConnection.id
output acsConnectionResourceId string = acsConnection.id
```

[image]

You can check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2016-06-01/connections?source=recommendations&pivots=deployment-language-bicep) for the web api connection bicep template.

Comment: Are you connecting to an Azure Communication Services resource e.g. email?  It looks like the connection is just a storage account. which I have already done multiple times.

Comment: I've implemented for the sample storage account. You can use the same process for the communication services.

Comment: Thanks Jahnavi, I have used the Microsoft.Web/Connections before when creating many API connections for Logic Apps.  However, as I detailed I cannot do the same for an Azure Communication Services resource, so that I can use it to send emails.  ACS is new and documentation and implementation is lacking.  I have tried all sorts of properties, but wonder if someone had success themselves with an API Connection towards an Azure Communication Services resource.